# Are Hellfire Amulet passives available on other classes?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Hellfire Amulet introduced in patch 2.1 has a secondary affix that adds the effect a random passive ability for your class. If you do this on Monk and get Fleet Footed (Increase movement speed by 10%), will this increase movement speed if worn by another class?

Comment: Note: asked at a time when some amulets on the PTR did not have (class only) text.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting close votes.  It's easily playable on the PTR, and that meets our definition of publicly available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  While another class can *wear* any Hellfire Amulet, the passives themselves only activate when the correct class is wearing them.  You can see this from the preview pictures of Hellfire Amulets on the PTR:

[image: Hellfire Amulets]

To be sure, some of the amulets don't have the (class only) text in them, but they will work the same.  It's on the PTR, bugs are to be expected.

Comment: Thanks. I asked because I saw items without the (class only) text.

Comment: At least what can be rolled as stats look decent compared to the ring. Did they change it on the PTR?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I think the Amulet is supposed to be an end-game item, so it can choose from the highest level affix pools.  That said, even a BIS ammy right now will have to give up at least one, probably two of the trifecta.  Because with legendary gems, a slot in your ammy will do you worlds of good.

Comment: Yes and no, I don't see a level requirement, like the ring, so it seems fit to help level up characters.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau It can be, and, really, probably will be, due to the stats on it.  I just don't think that that's it's primary use.